# Motorbike Lack of power/speed

Tags: motorcycle, power, rattle

I bought an ajs dd125e-8 it was delivered on Monday and I had no problems until yesterday on my way home from work.  I got half way home and the bike just started to slow down and no matter how much throttle input on it wouldn't do more than 30mph.  There is a small rattle but only just noticeable any chance someone knows what the problem is as I can't afford the delivery costs of getting it to the nearest dealer and I'm hoping it's something easy to fix.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a brand new bike? Also, your description is very vague. You could *possibly* pull the intake up to the carb or throttle body (which ever it has) and see if there are any obstructions. It could be that the throttle plate has come loose and is blocking the incoming air.

Comment: @arwelevans   Are you still experiencing this issue?